# Scope and statically known namespaces in XQuery

Tags: xquery, exist-db

consider a library module `ctx`

```
xquery version "3.1";

module namespace ctx="module/ctx"; 

declare function ctx:resolve (
    $ctx as function(xs:string) as xs:QName
) as function(xs:string, xs:integer) as function(*)? {
    function ($name as xs:string, $arity as xs:integer) as function(*)? {
        function-lookup($ctx($name), $arity)
    }
};
```

and a library module `a`

```
xquery version "3.1";

module namespace a="module/a"; 

declare function a:f () { "a:f" };
```

And a main module

```
xquery version "3.1";

import module namespace a="module/a" at "a.xqm";
import module namespace ctx="module/ctx" at "ctx.xqm";


ctx:resolve(xs:QName(?))("a:f", 0)()
```

Is it safe to assume that the function reference returned by `xs:QName(?)` will keep the context in which the namespace `a` is declared so that the main module will output "a:f"?

This does work in eXist-db (tested on 5.3.0) but I am not sure if this code is portable to other XQuery 3.1 processors.

---- UPDATE ----

What does not work in eXist-db 5.3.0 is

```
import module namespace ctx="module/ctx" at "ctx.xqm";

declare namespace app = "app";
declare function app:f () { "app:f" };

ctx:resolve(xs:QName(?))("app:f", 0)()
```

Comment: opened related eXist-db issue https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/issues/4614

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an excellent question.

If you used a named function reference xs:QName#1, then you would find the answer in §3.1.6:

> Furthermore, if the function returned by the evaluation of a
> NamedFunctionRef has an implementation-dependent implementation, then
> the implementation of this function is associated with the static
> context of this NamedFunctionRef expression and with the dynamic
> context in which the NamedFunctionRef is evaluated.

That's rather arcane language, but what it means is that the function you get back uses the static and dynamic context of the named function reference itself (and not the context at the point where the function is actually called).

For a partial function application `xs:QName(?)` the language is even more impenetrable:

> Implementation: The implementation of F. If this is not an XQuery 3.1
> expression then the new function's implementation is associated with a
> static context and a dynamic context in one of two ways: if F's
> implementation is already associated with contexts, then those are
> used; otherwise, SC and DC are used.

I think the spec is assuming (without justification) that built in functions like `xs:QName` will have an implementation that is not an XQuery 3.1 expression, so the second sentence applies. I really don't know quite what it intends by the phrase "already associated with contexts" - perhaps it's concerned with the case where F is already a partially applied function. But in any case, I'm reasonably sure that the intent is that "SC and DC are used" - that is, `xs:QName(?)` works exactly like `xs:QName#1`, it uses the static and dynamic context at the point where the expression `xs:QName(?)` is evaluated.

You're quite right to be concerned that you can't assume that what existing products do is what the spec says must happen. But in this case, I think they are getting it right.

Comment: Good explanation. Maybe in 4.0 this can be stated in a more understandable manner? Maybe say something as: "A resolved function reference has the SC and DC existing at the location where the resolution was specified"? In other words, this is a closure of that (dynamic) point of evaluation.

Comment: Thank you Micheal Kay, that was what I was looking for. Now I have several bugs to file :)

Comment: - NamedFunctionRef in baseX `xs:QName#1` has access to dynamic context according to Dimitre Novachev (see XML-Slack)
- functions declared in main module namespace are not added to dynamic context in eXist-db

Comment: A link to the issue opened to reword the spec for cross-reference: https://github.com/qt4cg/qtspecs/issues/239

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to assume that the function reference returned by xs:QName(?) will keep the context in which the namespace a is declared so that the main module will output "a:f"?

Tested successfully with BaseX 10.3.

Had to fix `ctx` as it was deemed syntactically incorrect by BaseX (missing `as  <Type>`) for the result of `ctx:resolve()`. Just added `as function(*)?` . Here is the corrected code:

```
xquery version "3.1";

module namespace ctx="module/ctx"; 

declare function ctx:resolve (
    $ctx as function(xs:string) as xs:QName
) as function(xs:string, xs:integer) as function(*)? {
    function ($name as xs:string, $arity as xs:integer) as function(*)? {
        function-lookup($ctx($name), $arity)
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: It has to be `as function(*)?` as function-lookup is not guaranteed to return something, no?

Comment: Thanks, this is a good observation. Updated the answer.

Comment: Knowing that this works in baseX is already really good news. I would really  like to know if this _has_ to work. :)

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work, but of course I am not a "XQuery guy" :)

Comment: I can try executing this with my pure XPath library project (uses an extension function (written in XSLT) for loading the function libraries)